# Constexpr member function on l-value ref object: Clang and gcc disagree

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

When a class has a constexpr member function and that member function is being evaluated on an l-value object in a constexpr context, clang and gcc disagree whether the result is a constexpr value.
Why? Is there a workaround that needs neither default-constructability nor copy-constructability?

When the object is passed by value, both compilers succeed compiling.

Clang versions trunk, 8, 7: `static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression`

and

Gcc versions trunk, 8.1, 7.4: compiles with no error

```cpp
#include <array>

using A = std::array<int, 10>;

void foo(const A& a){
    // clang: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(a.size() > 0, "");
}


void foo2(A a){
    // this compiles on both clang and gcc
    static_assert(a.size() > 0, "");
}

// Some custom code with the same symptom:
class B{
  public:
    constexpr int size()const{
        return 42;
    }
};

void foo3(const B& b){
    // clang: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(b.size() > 0, "");
}


void foo4(B b){
    // this compiles on both clang and gcc
    static_assert(b.size() > 0, "");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9vmyli

Workarounds with caveats:

```cpp
void foo5(const B& b){
    // This works in clang, if the default constructor is defined
    static_assert(B().size() > 0, "");
}

void foo6(const B& b){
    // This works in clang, if the copy constructor is defined
    [](B b){static_assert(b.size() > 0, "");}(b);
}
```

Comment: You can define `size` as a static member function and use `B::size()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified by the definition of [core constant exprssions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions):

> A *core constant expression* is any expression whose evaluation would
>   not evaluate any one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> 12. an *id-expression* referring to a variable or a data member of reference type, unless it was initialized with a constant expression
>       or its lifetime began within the evaluation of this expression
>
> ...

So you are not allowed to have reference `const A& a` here.

As an example, the following snippet compiles fine:

```cpp
using A = std::array<int, 10>;

constexpr A arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
constexpr const A& arr_ref = arr;   // OK: arr_ref is initialized with a constant expr

static_assert(arr.size() > 0, "");
static_assert(arr_ref.size() > 0, "");
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you think of a workaround that is better than the one in the question in terms of `A` not needing to be default-constructible? `std::declval` has the same issue because it returns a reference. And a declaration of something like `constexpr A dummy();` is not enough, since `constexpr` needs the definition of `dummy`.