# clang and gcc disagree when calling static constexpr member function on a type deduced from an l-value reference type

Tags: c++, reference, clang, c++14, constexpr

There is a difference in the behavior of clang and gcc in the context of `constexpr` member function on l-value references already discussed here: [stackoverflow/question/57779870](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779870/constexpr-member-function-on-l-value-ref-object-clang-and-gcc-disagree)

I extended this to static function calls on the type, that is deduced from the l-value reference object and the following is still not working in clang:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Dummy class with static constexpr member function
class MyClass {
public:
static constexpr bool check(int id){return true;}
};

template<int id, typename someT>
static constexpr bool doWithDeduction(someT& argument){
    return std::remove_reference_t<someT>::check(id);
}

// Replaced argument type by a dummy int type, argument is not used anyway
template<int id, typename someT>
static constexpr bool doWithDeduction(int& argument){
    return std::remove_reference_t<someT>::check(id);
}


// No function arguments! this works!
template<int id, typename someT>
static constexpr bool doSomething(){
    return std::remove_reference_t<someT>::check(id);
}

// wrapper to pass by ref
void wrap(MyClass& arg, int& i) {

    // works with gcc & clang
    static_assert(doSomething<1, decltype(arg)>(), "assert");

    // The following are not integral constexpr according to clang

    // This is what I want (type deduction for arg)
    static_assert(doWithDeduction<1>(arg), "assert");

    // Even when the type is not deduced but given here, this does not compile in clang
    static_assert(doWithDeduction<1, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arg)>>(arg), "assert");

    // As soon as I pass somting(here int) as reference, clang complains about integral constant expressions
    static_assert(doWithDeduction<1, decltype(arg)>(i), "assert");
}

int main() {
    int i{1};
    MyClass myObject{};
    wrap(myObject, i);
}
```

This example is also available here: [online_example godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/wDvxvr) 
I am using gcc 9.2.0 and clang 9.0.1. -std=c++17 (or -std=c++14)

Can somebody explain, why not even the last to calls are working?
And which is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit perplexed with what gcc does here. Your `static_assert`s are not supplied with compile-time values. It is pretty reasonable for clang to reject the code since it seems to errornous. I mean - `wrap` is not `constexpr` and neither it is fed `constexpr` values. You cannot expect its contents to be evaluated at compile time then.